# Перехват данных из потока

Tags: python, requests

Я хочу сделать программу, которая берет аудиозапись из потока. Проблема в том, что мне нужно уметь остановить её в любой момент, иначе придется ждать окончание потока.

```
import requests
stop = 0
r = requests.get("http://ip/audio.wav", stream=True)
while True:
    with open("My_song.mp3", "wb") as f:
        f.write(r.content)
    break
```

Comment: Линукс или виндовс?

Comment: Операционная система - виндовс